# Error when I 'm trying to create message draft using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I used this instructions: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_messages

I got bearer token and users, but when I try create message using Postman it throw exception

My request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4850bf92-08ff-41f3-9891-51561239aaa54/messages
{
    "subject":"Did you see last night's game?",
    "importance":"Low",
    "body":{
        "contentType":"HTML",
        "content":"They were <b>awesome</b>!"
    },
    "toRecipients":[
        {
            "emailAddress":{
                "address":"user@mail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2b956003-3e1a-4d0d-b5dd-e7f17625e1ac",
            "date": "2018-10-04T17:13:57"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I asked this question to technical support and they gave answer, that this available only for Outlook accounts. But I need create and send message for user in Active Directory with another mail domain (like gmail.com, etc.)